# Rails - jquery plugin loaded in development but fails to load in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, production

I have the following in a view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'scrollable/jquery.tools.min.js' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'scrollable/scrollable-buttons' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'scrollable/scrollable-horizontal' %>
```

Because I have this plugin located in `/vendor/assets/javascripts/scrollable/` and `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/scrollable/`

I don't have any problems in development, but when trying to get into that page in production mode, the JS is not loading. I get this error:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://mysite/assets/scrollable/jquery.tools.min-707bfab8972e8e363a009148db789121.js"
```

Any thoughts please?

Notice that if I go to: `https://mysite/assets/scrollable/jquery.tools.min.js` - I can see the code. So I am guessing is some problem with the md5 fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like they're not getting precompiled? you can tell by checking if they're listed in public/assets/manifest.yml on production.

if that's the case, and you want to access them via the asset pipeline

- did you run rake assets:precompile on production?
- did you add the files to the config.assets.precompile array (in  config/environments/production.rb)? eg, 'scrollable/jquery.tools.min.js', ditto for css files.

if you don't want to use the asset pipeline, use your own include tags instead of the javascript_include_tag/stylesheet_link_tags, ie `<script src="/scrollable/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` for the js